# Xcode: debugging cocoa apps over virtual machine

Tags: xcode, cocoa

i need to debug my Cocoa app on different versions of OS X.
But I only have one Mac machine.
I use macOS sierra(10.12) on my iMac, and I  have installed El cap(10.11) on Vmware. Also i am going to install 10.10 as well

Xcode 8.1 is running on Sierra and I have no idea to target the El Cap on vmware. 
How can i let Xcode connect with the one on virtual machine so that it launches on El Cap on vmware?